# Ler arquivo csv que possui cabeçalho e coluna com virgulas

Tags: php, array

**Estou tentando ler um aquivo **csv** e salvar num array**, mas o problema é que a quarta coluna do arquivo **csv** que eu estando ler, possui um texto separado por vírgula, e isso faz com que quando eu leio o arquivo **csv**, o **php** separa o texto da coluna 4 em diferentes indexes do array.

Como faço para que o meu código ignore a coluna 4 ou para coloque o texto da coluna 4 somente em um index?

Esse é o meu codigo para ler o arquivo:

```
function readCsv($fileName)
{
         if(!file_exists($fileName) || !is_readable($fileName)) return false;

         $header = null;
         $data = array();
         $lines = file($fileName);
         foreach($lines as $line) {
             $values = str_getcsv($line, ',', '\\');
            if(!$header)
                 $header = $values;
             else 
                 $data[] = array_combine($header, $values);
         }
         return $data;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se o campo do seu csv contêm virgulas o mesmo deve ter um caracter de enclosure

Exemplo de uma linha com virgulas em que o enclosure é o carácter "

*Jim Grayson,Senior Manager,(555)761-2385,"Spoke Tuesday, he's interested"*

Se isso não acontecer o csv não está criado corretamente.
A função str_getcsv tem 1 parâmetro obrigatório e três opcionais, sendo que um deles é o enclosure

Por "padrão" da função se o parâmetro $enclosure não for passado assume o valor de "

Verifique qual é enclosure utilizado no seu csv, pode ser outro carácter diferente de "

Os campos com vírgula devem sempre que o delimiter for uma vírgula ter um enclosure se isso não acontecer serão lidos de forma errada.

Se o enclosure do seu csv for " , o $delimiter for uma vírgula e o escape \ poderá simplificar a chamada da função str_getcsv para

```
str_getcsv($input=$line)
```

Por fim tenha em consideração a ordem com que os parâmetros são passados para a função str_getcsv, segundo o manual:

```
array str_getcsv ( string $input [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\\" ]]] )
```

Answer (score -1):

O texto do seu cabeçalho deve conter aspas para que funciona com a virgula, porém o recomendado é que o cabeçalho não seja um texto e sim uma palavra.